# Android: How to make seprate class for BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android, class, encapsulation, numberpicker

I have bottom sheet dialog that displays when button clicked, so I have implemented all the logic for bottom sheet dialog into onClick method of button, how can I make separate class for showing bottom sheet dialog and just call method in onClick

Here is my code in onClick:

```
 BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
 View sheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, null);

 NumberPicker minutePicker = (NumberPicker) sheetView.findViewById(R.id.np);
 tv = (TextView) sheetView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

 minutePicker.setMaxValue(100);
 minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
 minutePicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

 mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
 mBottomSheetDialog.show();

 minutePicker.setOnValueChangedListener(
            new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                                             int newVal) {
            tv.setText(Integer.toString(newVal));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement separation of concern and make your code modular

```
public class ClsBottomSheet{

public static TextView tv;
LayoutInflater inflater;
BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog;
public static NumberPicker minutePicker;

public ClsBottomSheet(Context context) {
    mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public BottomSheetDialog showDialog(){
    View sheetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, null);
    minutePicker = (NumberPicker) sheetView.findViewById(R.id.np);
    tv = (TextView) sheetView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Button btnOne = (Button) sheetView.findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
    Button btnTwo = (Button) sheetView.findViewById(R.id.btn_two);

    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBottomSheetDialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    minutePicker.setMaxValue(100);
    minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
    minutePicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
    minutePicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new ClsCallback());

    return mBottomSheetDialog;
}
}
```